# Proving $\lim_{n \to \infty} 10000 (\log n)^{1000}/(n^{1.0001}/1000) = 0$

Tags: calculus, limits

Initially it seems that $10000(\log n)^{1000}$ is far greater than $n^{1.0001}/1000$, but Wolframalpha says that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{10000 (\log n)^{1000}}{1.0001 n^{1.0001}/1000} = 0$$

I can't think of the way of proving this. Can anyone suggest a way?

Comment: But there is not any $x$!

Comment: Sorry my mistake. Fixed x to n.

Comment: perhaps using l'hopital's rule?

Comment: Hint: the constants don't really matter.  So, all you need to look at is the $\log$ and the power function.

Comment: Hint: can you prove $\frac{\log(n)}{n^a}$ approaches $0$ for any $a>0$?

Comment: i think this expression essentially reduces to $\frac{1}{x^2}$ but I haven't checked through yet. 1/x^2 approaches 0 as x approaches infinity

Answer (score 2):

Your constant multipliers aren't relevant if the limit is zero. You can prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty} (\log n) / n^c = 0$ for any $c > 0$ using L'Hopital's rule. Then just raise your given formula to the $1/1000$ power.

Comment: but surely that would mess with the proof since you have already assumed the limit?

Comment: Raising to the $1000$ power and multiplying by constants are continuous functions that are $0$ at $0$, so if the limit is $0$ then so will be the limit after applying these transformations. By manipulating the power of $\log n$ to be $1$, it makes it much easier to see what the limit is (zero).

Comment: ok, so there's an easy way to check what the limit is only if it's zero. nice

Answer (score 1):

If the limit really is zero, the constant factor
$$\frac{10000}{1.0001\mathbin{/}1000}$$ doesn't matter at all. Without that factor, we're examining the limit of
$$\frac{{\log n}^{1000}}{n^{1.0001}},$$
which can be rewritten as
$$\frac{{\log 1000 n}}{n^{1.0001}}.$$
At this point, if you have a lot of experience with limits, your intuition will be telling you very loudly that the limit is indeed zero. The reason is that the thing on top is a logarithm of $n$ (even though the argument is really a large multiple of $n$), and the thing on the bottom is a power of $n$ (even though the power is really small). Powers grow *much* faster than logarithms, so this should be no contest: the bottom should win easily.

---

To turn that intuition into a proof, let's do some more formal reasoning. First, notice that $n \le n^{1.0001}$, so if $n$ can beat the thing on the top, $n^{1.0001}$ can *definitely* beat the thing on the top. That means it would be enough to prove that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log 1000n}{n}$$
is zero.

Next, it would be nice if we could get rid of the factor of $1000$ in the argument of $\log$. The easiest way to do this is to put a matching factor on the bottom: like before, this won't affect the limit if the limit is really zero. Now we're examining the limit of
$$\frac{\log 1000n}{1000n}$$
as $n \to \infty$. Making the substitution $m = 1000n$, we see this is the same as the limit of
$$\frac{\log m}{m}$$
as $m \to \infty$.

Before, our intuition that the limit had to be zero came from the fact that powers grow much faster than logarithms. Now we're in a position to formally apply that fact: it's a fundamental fact that
$$\lim_{m \to \infty} \frac{\log m}{m} = 0.$$
You should try to find a proof of this, either by looking it up or working it out yourself, if you haven't seen one before.

Finally, working backwards along our chain of reasoning, you can use the properties of limits to argue carefully that
$$\lim_{m \to \infty} \frac{\log m}{m} = 0$$
implies
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{{\log n}^{1000}}{n^{1.0001}} = 0,$$
which is what we wanted to show.